FastAPI - Shopify computed hmac not matching received one
I’m building a Shopify public app and I’m having trouble with the HMAC verification process. Despite using the Shopify Secret from the Dashboard of my app at partners.shopify.com, I can’t get the computed HMAC and the received HMAC to match. This always results in a failed verification.
I’ve tried various combinations, but nothing seems to work—they never match. There might be something I’m missing. I hope someone here has a solution.

The SHOPIFY_SECRET is the SECRET from partners dashboard of the current App.
The App is made to be public, I can't use the Webhooks key from admin shop, we have to use Secret App key.

Here is the current implementation using FastAPI.

def verify_webhook(data, hmac_header):
    # Compute HMAC using the raw data
    secret = SHOPIFY_SECRET.encode('utf-8')
    digest = hmac.new(secret, data, digestmod=sha256).digest()
    computed_hmac = base64.b64encode(digest).decode('utf-8')

    print("SECRET:", secret)
    print("DATA (raw):", data)
    print("DIGEST (binary):", digest)
    print("DIGEST (hex):", digest.hex())
    print("COMPUTED HMAC (base64):", computed_hmac)
    print("RECEIVED HMAC (header):", hmac_header)

    return hmac.compare_digest(computed_hmac, hmac_header)

@app.post('/webhook/customer/data_request')
async def customer_data_request_webhook(request: Request):
    try:
        data = await request.body()
        headers = dict(request.headers)

        print('RAW DATA:', data)
        print('HEADERS:', headers)

        hmac_header = headers.get('X-Shopify-Hmac-SHA256')
        print("HMAC HEADER:", hmac_header)

        verified = verify_webhook(data, hmac_header)
        if not verified:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail="HMAC verification failed")

        print("Received customer data request webhook:")
        print(data)
        return Response(status_code=HTTP_200_OK)

Thank you in advance,
Cheers,
Kevin
here are logs by the way
DATA b'{"shop_id":60225617942,"shop_domain":"app-security.myshopify.com"}'
HEADER {'host': '*******************', 'user-agent': 'Ruby', 'content-length': '66', 'accept': '*/*', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip', 'cdn-loop': 'cloudflare; subreqs=1', 'cf-connecting-ip': '34.23.252.48', 'cf-ew-via': '15', 'cf-ipcountry': 'US', 'cf-ray': '88f83610910badb0-ATL', 'cf-visitor': '{"scheme":"https"}', 'cf-worker': 'onrender.com', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'render-proxy-ttl': '4', 'rndr-id': '4e79bfd2-668d-4233', 'traceparent': '00-61fe6df471212a349f78bfef3aeb53bb-b94c865665aa5ace-01', 'true-client-ip': '34.23.252.48', 'x-cloud-trace-context': '61fe6df471212a349f78bfef3aeb53bb/13352194700877650638;o=1', 'x-forwarded-for': '34.23.252.48, 10.216.35.99', 'x-forwarded-proto': 'https', 'x-request-start': '1717674903202354', 'x-shopify-api-version': '2022-10', 'x-shopify-hmac-sha256': '4Apq2emHXH+wFrY3yTP9u+XUAMrb/pOl/HE0OMmqf1E=', 'x-shopify-shop-domain': 'app-security.myshopify.com', 'x-shopify-test': 'true', 'x-shopify-topic': 'shop/redact', 'x-shopify-trace-context': '61fe6df471212a349f78bfef3aeb53bb/13352194700877650638;o=1', 'x-shopify-trace-hint': 'true', 'x-shopify-triggered-at': '2024-06-06T11:55:03.059362171Z', 'x-shopify-webhook-id': '3c7cc95f-e354-46f4-87b4-8da946b988df'}
HMAC HEADER 4Apq2emHXH+wFrY3yTP9u+XUAMrb/pOl/HE0OMmqf1E=
SECRET: b'********************************'
DATA (raw): b'{"shop_id":60225617942,"shop_domain":"app-security.myshopify.com"}'
DIGEST (binary): b':\x00\xe2\x01\xf5\x88\x8c\xfb,H\\\x88\x9a\xe6\xd7\xaa\x13\x18M\xd2\xcdY\x00\x16L\x12\xda\xbf-\x88N\x16'
COMPUTED HMAC (base64): OgDiAfWIjPssSFyImubXqhMYTdLNWQAWTBLavy2IThY=
RECEIVED HMAC (header): 4Apq2emHXH+wFrY3yTP9u+XUAMrb/pOl/HE0OMmqf1E=
Error processing shop data erasure webhook:
401: HMAC verification failed


I faced a similar problem, but we were using Node Express in the backend.
Then I had to sort the data (query param) in a specific format (key = value) and then had to use the HEX digest mode.
Here is another post  that may help you solve the issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61772413/base64-hmac-with-sha256-in-python

Thank you for your reply. I tried sorting keys and using specific separators as suggested in the other post (also using hex instead of base64), but the format of the HMAC is no longer the same. Even if the computed HMAC was wrong in my previous trials, the HMAC format was correct. I also heard that hex is for OAuth HMAC for Shopify, while base64 is for webhook HMACs. I can’t figure out what I am doing wrong; it seems like HMAC verification from Shopify is a pain for a lot of developers.

Understood. If you want I can try converting my JS code to python. I know python but not well versed in it. So I can't guarantee, will it work or not.

Thank you for your answer! Actually I think the problem lies in how I’am fetching the payload or in the way I’am digesting it. But I can’t find a way to confirm the structure of the expected payload. If you can send that part of your js I can convert it to python. Anyway, thank you very much for your time and involvement, I really appreciate it.

No problem. Sharing it as an answer.

As per our discussion above, I am sharing the logic in JS that worked for me.
const verifyShopifyRequest = async (shopifySecret, query) => {
    try {
        if (!(query && shopifySecret)){ 
            console.log(`Invalid query or secret <<--------- verifyShopifyRequest = ERROR`);
            return false;
        }

        const { signature = "", ...otherQueryParams } = query;

        const input = Object.keys(otherQueryParams)
            .sort()
            .map((key) => {
                const value = otherQueryParams[key];
                return `${key}=${value}`;
            })
            .join("");

        const hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha256", shopifySecret).update(input).digest("hex");

        const digest = Buffer.from(hmac, "utf-8");
        const checksum = Buffer.from(signature, "utf-8");

        if(!(digest.length === checksum.length && crypto.timingSafeEqual(digest, checksum))) return false;

        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error, ` <<--------- verifyShopifyRequest = ERROR`);
        return false;
    }
}

A possible equivalent for the above logic in Python:
import hashlib
import hmac

def verify_shopify_request(shopify_secret, query):
    try:
        if not (query and shopify_secret):
            print("Invalid query or secret <<--------- verify_shopify_request = ERROR")
            return False

        signature = query.pop('signature', '')

        input_string = ''.join(f"{key}={value}" for key, value in sorted(query.items()))

        hmac_digest = hmac.new(shopify_secret.encode('utf-8'), input_string.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

        if not (len(hmac_digest) == len(signature) and hmac.compare_digest(hmac_digest, signature)):
            return False

        return True
    except Exception as error:
        print(f"{error} <<--------- verify_shopify_request = ERROR")
        return False


Thank you for sharing! Do you also use this for webhook or only for OAuth?

OAuth only.
Did it work?

It do work for OAuth, but not for Webhook. Thank you for that !

Would you then please mark it as accepted answer?
